# Javascript not calling from Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have this visualforce page and it does not appear to be running the javascript OnKeyUp.  Any ideas why this is not calling on each key-up?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function doSearch() {
        searchServer(
          document.getElementById("clientName").value);
      }
  </script>  

 <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="results,debug,errors">
      <apex:param name="clientName" value="" />          
  </apex:actionFunction>

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Client Name<br/>
    <input type="text" id="clientName" onkeyup="doSearch()"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it should work. do you see any error in console? can you add console.log before searchServer method call inside doSearch method to make sure it is working ?

Comment: Perfect use case for visual force remoting and not an action function.

Comment: @Himanshu like this:  function doSearch() {
            console.log;
              searchServer(
              document.getElementById("clientName").value,
              document.getElementById("clientDOB").value,
              document.getElementById("benefitAmount").value,
              document.getElementById("FamilySize").value);
          }

Comment: @Eric could you elaborate on this?

Comment: like following console.log('*******Inside console*************');

Comment: I added this:   function doSearch() {
            console.log('sdfdsffd');
              searchServer(

In the logs panel I'm not seeing anything generated when I type?  How can I get at the log that's being generated?

Comment: Do a search for autocomplete in visualforce

Comment: @Himanshu adding  function doSearch() {
              window.alert("sometext"); shows an alert so the javascript is getting called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely to have some problems running an actionFunction on keyup. This is because Salesforce will take longer to process your request than it takes a user to type each letter. This results in a long queue of requests and some odd performance. Ideally, you want to use a timeout via javascript's `window.setTimeout` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function. Every time you get a keyUp event, cancel the previous event with `window.clearTimeout()` and add a new event for `doSearch()` for ~500ms in the future. This way, when the user stops typing for half a second, your actionFunction gets invoked, but it is not continuously invoked as the user types. You can play around with that delay to get your desired behavior.

EDIT - Here is some sample JS code that accomplishes what I was referring to:

```
<input id="clientName" type="text" onkeyUp="queueSearch()" />
<script>
  var currentQueueId;
  var queueDelay = 500; // in ms
  var queueSearch = function() {

    // clear any old event
    window.clearTimeout(currentQueueId);

    // add a new event
    currentQueueId = window.setTimeout(doSearch, queueDelay);
  }

  var doSearch = function() {
    var searchTerm = document.getElementById("clientName").value;

    actionFunction(searchTerm);
  }

  // This would actually be your apex:actionFunction
  var actionFunction = function(searchTerm) {
    alert(searchTerm);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: that's great!   However, even if I made these changes to the javascript wouldn't the result be the same because it's not being called?

Comment: When you say "not being called" do you mean that the function is never invoked? It can sometimes be tricky to determine where the process is actually having an issue. If you add the `oncomplete="alert(0);"` attribute to your `apex:actionFunction`, does the alert show? If so, check that your page doesn't contain any required fields that are missing and check that your `rerender` attribute contains an `apex:pageMessages` element so that any errors can be updated on the page.

Comment: I added this and I don't see an alert when I type.  Where the should alert show?   <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="results,debug,errors", oncomplete="alert(0);">

Comment: I added it and no alert is showing up when I add something to those text boxes.

Comment: The alert would show as a browser alert (it pops up right in your face). Since that is not working you want to take a step back and add the alert to your `doSearch` function. If that still does not show the alert there is something up with your actual onkeyup event on your input.

Comment: function doSearch() {  window.alert("sometext");  Shows an alert.

Comment: Great, you are making some progress then! So you know that your helper function is getting called, but your actionFunction is not. Try changing the `action` on your `actionFunction` to `action="{!null}"` to have it not do anything and see if that shows your alert when it completes (doing nothing).

Comment: I changed it to {!null} and I still get the alert

Comment: I can get it to display 'in' but not 'out'.  window.alert('in');            
              searchServer(
              document.getElementById("clientName").value,
              window.alert('out');

Comment: This means your document.getElementById is probably failing. Open the javascript console in your browser and look for errors.

Comment: That was the issue.  I was able to get in and out.  The console pointed out that ElementsByID are case sensitive!  All that time!  Well lesson learned.  Read the console.  How can I mark that comment as the answer?

Comment: @tjcinnamon - Had you posted your actual code we could have helped you much quicker (another lesson) - See, your case in your code (the id `clientName` and the ..byid.. `clientName` match case and your `getElementById` is correct) which means that what was in your SF Code was NOT what was posted here. Keep that in mind next time when asking a question.....Of course I could be misunderstanding what you are saying in your comment to....

Comment: @tjcinnamon - Can;t mark the comment as an answer just mark the answer itself as the answer and the Original answerer will update the answer if you ask.

Comment: I think this question took a few turns. Was the original issue that you had a `document.getElementById`with an invalid id (because of case)? If you have fixed that specific issue I still encourage you to use the above pattern. For better performance you could use the pattern with Visualforce Remoting but you will be responsible for rendering the result HTML. This could be helped with a templating library (http://www.kineticgrowth.com/how-to-use-handlebars-js-template-visualforce-remoting/). This is getting much more advanced than your original question but I think is valuable to the community.

Comment: Let me know and I will update my answer.

Comment: yes, the document.getElementByID was case sensitive and using the debug tools helped to find it.  That would be the official answer.  I want to make sure you get credit.